# Error when deleting row at UITableView (only in iOS7)

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios7, cell

I had my app running cool in iOS6, but when I updated for iOS7 with the same code I was working with, I get this error when I try to delete a row in a table :

```
2013-10-02 17:44:11.344 Goal[1877:a0b] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView
     _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2903.2/UITableView.m:1330
2013-10-02 17:44:11.384 Goal[1877:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception     'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows 
in section    0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the
 update (1) must be equal to    the number of rows contained in that section 
before the update (1), plus or minus the number   of rows inserted or 
 deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or 
  minus the      number of rows moved into or out of that section  
(0 moved in, 0 moved out).'
```

here's some methods if you need it

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        // deleting
        NSManagedObjectContext *moc = self.managedObjectContext;
        Goal *goalToDelete = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [moc deleteObject:goalToDelete];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }

}
```

another one

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"GoalCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

// Configure the cell...
cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

Goal *goal = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.textLabel.text = goal.title;

return cell;
}
```

and no I didnt forget to check my cell identifier,

Answer (score 2):

I guess you're getting an error because you're calling `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` twice: once in `commitEditingStyle` and another time in your `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` methods after updating your MOC.

But the real problem is you shouldn't be calling `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` at all.

When a row is deleted by a user action, the table view informs **you** through the `commitEditingStyle` delegate method. Your job is then to update your data model to be consistent with what the table view already knows. You do not need to inform the table.

It is only when you programmatically modify your data model that you need to inform the table view by calling the insert/delete/move methods.

Comment: Your comment about not calling `deleteRowsAtIndexPath` in `commitEditingStyle` is incorrect. 


[From the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:):


"The **data source** commits the insertion or deletion by invoking the UITableView methods insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation: or deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:, as appropriate."

Comment: @Rizwan You're absolutely right. Thanks for pointing that out. I went back and looked at my own code and indeed `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` was being called indirectly in another method. Seems a bit odd to me that `commitEditingStyle` and `moveRowAtIndexPath` work differently in that regard.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty clear:

- Number of rows before the update = 1
- Number of rows deleted = 1
- Number of rows after update = 1 (this should be 0)

Your numberOfRowsAtIndexPath method implementation is wrong. It should return 1 less than the number of rows before deletion. This method's return value should match the number of rows you expect to have on your UITableView.

Also, your code will crash on any iOS version, not just 7.

Answer (score 1):

Before calling    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
decrease "numberOfRows" that numberOfRowsInSection function returns.

Comment: If you have a more advanced implementation of a UITableViewSource, where you have a variable, property or method keeping track of the number of rows (in section if using sections), Mehmet is right that you'll have to make sure that the number of rows is decreased.

Right before deleteRowsAtIndexPath is called, the number of rows must be decreased by the number of rows that was deleted.

Thanks Mehmet!